# something not going properly with an import script

Tags: php, mysql, csv, file-import

I have this script which permits me to insert a csv file content into mysql, now, my problem is, i don't know why it puts the fields of date and mobile number in the same place. Both date and mobile number are different fields in the database, both varchar types.

now, this is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
        echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
        readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
    }

    //Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $import="INSERT into imovo(date,time,location,rbpos_id,mobile_number) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]')";

        mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    fclose($handle);

    print "Import done";
```

It won't upload the data properly.
Here is how it uploads the data, and the data won't go all into the database:

```
8/31/12,12:34:40,Tirane1,2345,662080090 8/32/2012,15:34:40 PM,Tirane2,2345,662080091 8/33/2012,18:34:40 PM,Tirane3,2345,662080092Import done
```

If you see, the date and mobile number go together..

Comment: can you please post sample of your csv?

Comment: http://penelope-ns.net/imovo-1.zip

Answer (score 0):

Mobile number and date don't go together, this space between them means another record (it's a new line in source code). It's the same as at the end, when print "Import done" sticks to mobile number.

Maybe the problem is that there's no such time as:

```
18:34:40 PM
```

It's either 18:34:40 or 6:34:40 PM

Comment: It must be something with my csv you are saying.. you gotta be right!